# Android: button action inside fragment

Tags: android, button, fragment

I am trying to trigger an action from a button which is in a fragment. The code does not point to errors however my Toast is never triggered.

**Do you know if the methods below make sense?**

These are my fragment methods:

```
View.OnClickListener myAction = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "AccountView", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account_view, container, false);
    accountButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    accountButton.setOnClickListener(myAction);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account_view, container, false);
}
```

Comment: during return u are inflating the view again...which invalidates the previous listener...

Comment: because you return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account_view, container, false);  so further initialization so only return only return view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY THIS

please replace your onCreateView with below code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account_view, container, false);
    accountButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    accountButton.setOnClickListener(myAction);

    return view; //change here
}
```

It is because you are creating view again. That is you are returning `inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account_view, container, false);`

Answer (score 1):

You should return the inflated view :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account_view, container, false);
    accountButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    accountButton.setOnClickListener(myAction);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it would probably fix it but the previous answer came first therefore I selected it as the answer.

Comment: I am pretty sure I was the first to answer, but never mind, I'm glad you fixed the problem anyway.

Answer (score 1):

return the view object in fragment:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account_view, container, false);
    accountButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    accountButton.setOnClickListener(myAction);

    return view;
}
```

And for showing toast use:

```
    View.OnClickListener myAction = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "AccountView", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it would probably fix it but the previous answer came first therefore I selected it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account_view,container,false);
  accountButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
  accountButton.setOnClickListener(myAction);

  return view;
}
```